# method for versioning configuration of civicrm?

Tags: configuration, configandlog

Is there a way to version the configuration so we can just roll it back if its a bit broken? Or is the only option full filesystem and db backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesnt seem to be, so I have gone with just regular full backups, and keeping a list of all the changes that I made as I go along, so I can keep track and undo them ;)

Comment: Did you also see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/reproduce-civicrm-configuration-best-practice which was added after your question and then included my answers above but also added some more.

Comment: thanks @Demerit thats very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

There is the CiviConfigure extension but I'm not sure how current it is.

There is also still bin/csv/export.php which you can use for option values and tags and such.

You can also use the api to retrieve and set various entities, e.g. using the cv tool.

For CiviCase, one of the original arguments for using external files was for versioning and managing dev/production. You can still use xml files for its config.