# How can I commit civicrm configs to git?

Tags: custom-fields, civicrm.settings.php, drupal-8

I am exploring civicrm and am trying to set up a prod, staging, dev environment where by I create and test custom fields in dev and deploy them to prod. What is the best way to do this?

I cam using the Drupal 8 version which has a config export feature, I am wondering if civicrm has something similar. Thanks

Comment: There's a good answer at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/reproduce-civicrm-configuration-best-practice

Comment: Thank you. It looks promising