# Is it possible to copy the "structure" from one CiviCRM install to another without copying data?

Tags: wordpress, installation

We are testing in a locally hosted config (easy to rollback if something goes wrong, thank you VirtualBOX!) and I am wondering if it is possible to copy the config from the local install to our hosted Wordpress install once we have it all sorted out?  It wouldn't be the worst thing if not possible but it certainly would be a time saver if it is possible.  Any comments/advice/warnings would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reproduce CiviCRM configuration: best practice](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/reproduce-civicrm-configuration-best-practice)

Comment: Hi, Demerit:  That article might have some answers.  Thanks for pointing it out.