# how to create a CiviCRM Drupal distribution?

Tags: drupal

The makers space where I've got my lab set up uses a bunch of disparate web software, resulting in numerous inefficiencies that waste staff time and dampen member experience.  Being a Drupal developer with a little experience in CiviCRM... I'm wondering: **what does it take to package up CiviCRM configurations into an installation script?**

There are numerous features that this makers space (and I suspect many others) would benefit from such as:

- case management for "incident reports" (broken tools, and various others)
- booking/reservations
- discussions (not a CiviCRM thing, but would be an integrated part of the distribution)
- among others

I did a little scripting (in a Drupal custom module) with the CiviCRM API... and was mostly just creating contacts&relationships and so forth.  Is it possible to define things like case types with the API?

Is there any other way to programmatically configure CiviCRM?

I assume there's no build/packaging system for config... but maybe there are some clever things that could be done in lieu of a mechanism like Drupal's features module?

Comment: Here's the community wiki answer to a similar question https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/30474/181

Comment: thanks @Demerit.  I just voted to close this question as a duplicate of the one you shared.