Configuration as code in CiviCRM
I'm working on a Drupal/CiviCRM site and would like to manage as much of the site's configuration as possible using git.
My goals are:

Improve local developer experience (local, staging, prod)
Disable UI configuration on the production site
Track the history of what's been done and why

In drupal this is possible with the drush config:export and drush config:import along with the Configuration Splits and Config Ignore modules.
How would I accomplish this in CiviCRM?

Perhaps you could say a little more about what you mean by "configuration"? CiviCRM has a lot of configurable data!

Thank you Coleman. Aside from user, email, payment, and other data, I'd like as much as possible in code. I realized this might not be possible and I'll take anything I can get. Off the top of my head, I'd like custom fields, options, extension settings, etc.

This is the "community wiki" answer to this question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30438/reproduce-civicrm-configuration-best-practice/30474#30474

Awesome! Thank you @Demerit! This is exactly what I was looking for!

I just updated item #2 in that community wiki answer to reflect the powerful new civix export command for exporting managed entities to an extension
